# How to do deep merge JSON in jackson 2?

Tags: json, jackson, jackson-modules

I am using Jersey and Jackson2 to development a Restful API. We have a problem when we development PUT method. Our PUT method is kind of like PATCH method. It will only updates the properties received in the request body.

I am using ObjectMapper.readerForUpdating() method to do object merging. But this method only support first level merge. For instance: I have an existed JSON object

```
{
  "a": "this is a",
  "b": "this is b",
  "c": {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2
  }
}
```

And then I receive a JSON object likes

```
{
  "a": "this is a new a",
  "c": {
    "x": 3
  }
}
```

I expect the merged object should be like:

```
{
  "a": "this is a new a",
  "b": "this is b",
  "c": {
    "x": 3,
    "y": 2
  }
}
```

But the result is

```
{
  "a": "this is a new a",
  "b": "this is b",
  "c": {
    "x": 3,
    "y": null
  }
}
```

The first level properties are merged correctly. But for the deep level, it is doing the object replacement. Is there any way to do deep merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, you will have to do that manually by traversing JSON trees (`JsonNode`) yourself, updating properties. There may be extension libraries that build on Jackson that provide support for this, but core Jackson databind only has "shallow" merge of single (root JSON Object) level.

Comment: Do you know the names of those libraries/extensions?

Answer (score 0):

For two given `JsonNode`s you can now do:

```
JsonNode result = MAPPER.updateValue(a, b);
```

[This was implemented 2017](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1556).

Answer (score -1):

I was going through the documentation of @JsonMerge of jackson-databind( com.fasterxml.jackson.core) v 2.11 and found that they have started supporting deep merge. However I have not tried using it.

Comment: I tried @JsonMerge from 2.11.0. It still does not work. It is appending instead of merging. May be I am doing something wrong. Did anyone get it working?

Comment: The code that I am using is 
    `mapper.readerForUpdating(toBeUpdatedJsonPayload).readValue(updateToBeAppliedToDestination);` In the above line of code `"toBeUpdatedJsonPayload"` is the POJO object with fields marked @JsonmMerge and `"updateToBeAppliedToDestination"` is a json string.

Comment: If a feature does not work, might be worth asking on mailing list and possibly file a Github issue. Deep merge should work, as you indicated. But your comment suggests you would not only expect case mentioned here (Objects) to be merged, but somehow JSON Arrays too -- those are much trickier as there is not just one obvious way to combine two sequences of things. Append is one (and is used) but perhaps you expect something else.